# Не работает команда giveaway Discord.py

Tags: discord.py

Увидел на просторах интернета команду giveaway решил проверить, суть данного кода что задается 3 вопроса и после ответа на первый, выдается второй вопрос. Но проблема в том что после первого вопроса второй вопрос не выдается.
Код был взят с этого видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QT4jolyyxVA&t=632s

Вот код:

```
def convert(time):
    pos = ["s","m","h","d"]

    time_dict = {"s" : 1, "m" : 60, "h" : 3600, "d": 3600*24}

    unit = time[-1]

    if unit not in pos:
        return -1
    try:
        val = int(time[:-1])
    except:
        return -2

    return val * time_dict[unit]

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def giveaway(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Начнем с этой раздачи! Ответьте на эти вопросы в течение 15 секунд!")

    questions = ["На каком канале он должен быть размещен?", "Какова должна быть продолжительность розыгрыша призов? (s|m|h|d)", "Какой приз в розыгрыше?"]

    answers = []

    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel

    for i in questions:
        await ctx.send(i)

        try:
            msg = await client.wait_for('messsage', timeout=15.0, check=check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await ctx.send('Вы не ответили вовремя, пожалуйста, в следующий раз поторопитесь!')
            return
        else: 
            answers.append(msg.content)

    try:
        c_id = int(answers[0][2:-1])
    except:
        await ctx.send(f"Вы неправильно упомянули канал. Делайте это так {ctx.channel.mention} в следующий раз.")
        return

    channel = client.get_channel(c_id)

    time = convert(answers[1])
    if time == -1:
        await ctx.send(f"Вы не ответили правильным блоком. В следующий раз используйте (s|m|h|d)!")
        return
    elif time == -2:
        await ctx.send(f"Время должно быть целым числом. Пожалуйста, введите в следующий раз целое число.")
        return
  
    prize = answers[2]

    await ctx.send(f"Розыгрыш будет через {channel.mention} и будет длиться {answers[1]} секунды!")

    embed = discord.embed(title = "Раздача!", description = f"{prize}", color = ctx.author.color)

    embed.add_field(name = "Создал:", value = ctx.author.mention)

    embed.set_footer(text = f"Заканчивается {answers[1]} ")

    my_msg = await channel.send(embed = embed)

    await my_msg.add_reaction("")

    await asyncio.sleep(time)

    new_msg = await channel.fetch_message(my_msg.id)

    users = await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
    users.pop(users.index(client.user))

    winner = random.choice(users)

    await channel.send(f"Поздравляю! {winner.mention} выиграл приз: {prize}!")

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def reroll(ctx, channel : discord.TextChannel, id_ : int):
    try:
        new_msg = await channel.fetch_message(id_)
    except:
        await ctx.send("Введенный идентификатор был неверным, убедитесь, что вы ввели правильный идентификатор сообщения с раздачей.")
        return   
    users = await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten()
    users.pop(users.index(client.user))

    winner = random.choice(users)

    await channel.send(f"Поздравляем нового победителя: {winner.mention} розыгрыша!")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в этой строке в параметре `message` указано `meSSSage` :)

```
msg = await client.wait_for('messsage', timeout=15.0, check=check)
```

Уберите лишнюю `s`

---

У вас потом возникнет еще одна ошибка, потому что в этой строке вы указали объект `Embed` с маленькой буквы.

```
embed = discord.embed(title="Раздача!", description=f"{prize}", color=ctx.author.color)
```

Правильно будет так:

```
embed = discord.Embed(title="Раздача!", description=f"{prize}", color=ctx.author.color)
```